# FFMPEG not "cutting" as expected

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am using FFMPEG (from a java application) via a simple system.process and trying to cut a video into chunks.  I am attempting to cut it into 10 second increments.  My FFMPEG commands look like:

```
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo.mp4 -ss 00:00:00.00 -t 00:00:10.00 -strict -2 1438458522836/1438458522836_0.mp4
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.01 -t 00:00:20.00 -strict -2 1438458522836/1438458536306_1.mp4
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo.mp4 -ss 00:00:20.01 -t 00:00:30.00 -strict -2 1438458522836/1438458546042_2.mp4
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo.mp4 -ss 00:00:30.01 -t 00:00:40.00 -strict -2 1438458522836/1438458561165_3.mp4
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo.mp4 -ss 00:00:40.01 -t 00:00:50.00 -strict -2 1438458522836/1438458577187_4.mp4
ffmpeg -i SampleVideo.mp4 -ss 00:00:50.01 -t 00:01:00.00 -strict -2 1438458522836/1438458587935_5.mp4
```

They look correct to me but my videos are not coming out in 10 second increments.  They seem to be getting "split" in random spots.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

For reference:

```
video 0 == 10 seconds
video 1 == 20 seconds
Video 2 == 30 seconds
Video 3 == 32 seconds
Video 4 == 22 seconds
Video 5 == 12 seconds
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the [FFMPEG documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options):

> -ss position (input/output)
>   When used as an input option (before `-i`), seeks in this input file to position. **Note the in most formats it is not possible to seek exactly, so ffmpeg will seek to the closest seek point before position.** When transcoding and -accurate_seek is enabled (the default), this extra segment between the seek point and position will be decoded and discarded. When doing stream copy or when -noaccurate_seek is used, it will be preserved.
>
> When used as an output option (before an output filename), decodes but discards input until the timestamps reach position.
>
> position may be either in seconds or in `hh:mm:ss[.xxx]` form.

So, you won't get an exact starting point, but since `-t` stops "listening" when the pointer hits the specified time, you don't get uniform times, but they all end when you want.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I appreciate the help.  I am sorry for so much hand holding but I think that I am missing something.  I tried to look in the documentation but no luck yet.  You said, "Note the in most formats it is not possible to seek exactly, so ffmpeg will seek to the closest seek point before position."

I actually do need very accurate splitting.  i will need to split at the millisecond (should I seek for a specific frame?).  Is there a recommended approach to this?  Again, all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help. Are the current videos that are output starting at their equivalent times? For example, the third video you specified ("Video 2") is thirty seconds long and the others are combined 30 seconds. Does "Video 2" start at `00:00:30` and end at `00:01:00`?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I will have to take a single video and break it down into smaller pieces.  Do some processing and then reassemble (strange I know).  Unfortunately each "piece" will be of a different length.  The starting point for each piece will be the ending point from the previous chunk.

Does that help?

Comment: I think that I cracked it.  I have switched to using this command an it appears to be cutting at the exact spots....

ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00.0 -i SampleVideo.mp4  -t 00:00:10.000 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 output.mp4

Comment: @user1815241: Awesome. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: hi, i used same command for android but gives me different output. Please suggest on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403348/ffmpeg-not-cutting-as-expected-in-android

Comment: -strict doesn't seem to work for me. What is it that -strict actually does in this case?

Answer (score 4):

Faced the same problem today with following command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:55.25 -i input.mp4 -t 00:00:04.75 -c copy output.mp4
```

This consistently gave me outputs with duration off by a couple of seconds.
Following [this explanation](https://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_seeking_ss_option_cutting_section_video_image.php) I reframed the command to this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:00:55.25 -to 00:01:00.0 -c copy output.mp4
```

and now the accuracy ranges from 0 to 0.02 sec.

Comment: Are you missing the -i in your second command line?

Comment: I have the same problem. I need accuracy of at least 0.01s. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sorry, 0.02 sec was good enough for me so I didn't investigate any further.