# FFMPEG not “cutting” as expected in Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, trim, cut

I referred [FFMPEG not "cutting" as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31765674/ffmpeg-not-cutting-as-expected) to split video in chunks in below format:

00:00:00 - 00:00:01

00:00:01 - 00:00:02

00:00:02 - 00:00:03

00:00:03 - 00:00:04

00:00:04 - 00:00:05

Here is the command i used:

```
String[] cmd1 = new String []{"-ss", "00:00:00.000", "-i", inputVideoUrl, "-t", "00:00:01.000", "-c:v", "libx264", "-strict", "-2", outputPath};

String[] cmd2 = new String []{"-ss", "00:00:01.000", "-i", inputVideoUrl, "-t", "00:00:02.000", "-c:v", "libx264", "-strict", "-2", outputPath};

String[] cmd3 = new String []{"-ss", "00:00:02.000", "-i", inputVideoUrl, "-t", "00:00:03.000", "-c:v", "libx264", "-strict", "-2", outputPath};

String[] cmd4 = new String []{"-ss", "00:00:03.000", "-i", inputVideoUrl, "-t", "00:00:04.000", "-c:v", "libx264", "-strict", "-2", outputPath};

String[] cmd5 = new String []{"-ss", "00:00:04.000", "-i", inputVideoUrl, "-t", "00:00:05.000", "-c:v", "libx264", "-strict", "-2", outputPath};
```

And i use this library:
https://github.com/teanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

```
implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.2.2.LTS'
```

When i execute i get the duration starting from beginning of the video all the time. Please suggest what am i doing wrong, i searched and tried changing commands but nothing works.

00:00:00 - 00:00:01

00:00:00 - 00:00:02

00:00:00 - 00:00:03

00:00:00 - 00:00:04

00:00:00 - 00:00:05

Let me share another example to explain my requirement:
inputVideoUrl contains a video of any length(ex: 5min)
I want to cut a user selected portion of it(ex first one minute) in the form of 5 split videos.

split 1: 00 sec - 12.0sec

split 2: 12.1 sec - 24.0sec

split 3: 24.1 sec - 36.0sec

split 4: 36.1 sec - 48.0sec

split 5: 48.1 sec - 60.0sec

And later i will provide these split videos to a player playlist.

Answer (score 0):

## Use the segment muxer

You can do everything with one command with the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment):

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f segment -segment_time 1 -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*1)" -reset_timestamps 1 output_%03d.mp4
```

The numerical value in `expr:gte(t,n_forced*1)` should equal the `-segment_time` value (which is `1` in this example).

Comment: thanks, i referred your solution mentioned in stackexchange and below comment splits fine: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time 1 -reset_timestamps 1 output_%03d.mp4        But  my actual requirement is not to segment complete video. For example i have a 1 min video(input.mp4), select the first second split and then divide it to five segments. Please suggest if there is command to achieve it or 5 commands also fine for me like in the question.

Comment: And how can i change the starting time("00:00:00.000",) with segments? . in my case it can be greater than 0.

Comment: @AneesU *"select the first second split and then divide it to five segments"*. Not exactly sure what you want. Provide example timestamps of the segments you want from 1 min video. *"And how can i change the starting time("00:00:00.000",) with segments?"* Use the `-ss` option.

Comment: thanks, i have updated the question to explain the requirement, kindly suggest.

Comment: @AneesU Can you provide a link to the input that does not split properly using the method as shown in your question? Or at least show an example of a ffmpeg command as executed (without the variables) and provide the complete log from the ffmpeg process.